# Can't override base property

Tags: c#

The follow is bad code. Please help me achieve what I'm trying to achieve, but with good code.
I want to have an object array that is derived from a base.  I want to be able to use that array in BaseClass when DoStuff() runs.  I know that I cannot downcast, that's not what i'm looking to do here. I just want to be able to set Fields in the derived class, and use Fields in the base DoStuff().

```
public class BaseObject
{

}

public class DerivedObject : BaseObject
{

}

public class BaseClass
{
    public BaseObject[] Objects;

    public virtual void DoStuff()
    {
        // use the Objects
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public override DerivedObject[] Objects;

    public override void DoStuff()
    {
        // Do stuff unique to the derived.

        base.DoStuff();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking for generics?

```
public class BaseClass<T>
where T : BaseObject
{
    public T[] Objects;

    public virtual void DoStuff()
    {
        // use the Objects
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass<DerivedObject>
{
    public override void DoStuff()
    {
        // Do stuff unique to the derived.

        base.DoStuff();
    }
}
```

In the above code field of `T` type (generic or parameter type) is declared, `T` is constrained to be `BaseObject` or class inherited from `BaseObject`, when `DerivedClass` is declared `DerivedObject` is specified in place of T, so in `DerivedClass` `Objects` field can be used as `DerivedObject[]`.

Comment: Possibly, but that seems like overkill.

Comment: Now that I take a second look at it, this probably works best. I'll try it.

Comment: @Matthew: in the other case you will need to cast your Objects field in the DerivedClass.

Comment: Ok, I've tested this and it works.  It is important to make sure you override Objects in DerivedClass, otherwise when DoStuff() runs in BaseClass, Fields will be null.

Comment: @Matthew if fields in DoStuff() are null than you just haven't initialized them before DoStuff was called.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the Property correctly, it should look like

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public virtual BaseObject[] Objects {get; set;}

    public virtual void DoStuff()
    {
        // use the Objects
    }
}
```

Then you should be able to override it as

```
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public override BaseObject[] Objects {get; set;}

    public override void DoStuff()
    {
        // Do stuff unique to the derived.

        base.DoStuff();
    }
}
```

It has to have the same name as the base object.

Comment: What's the point of overriding here if you don't change the implementation?

Comment: I don't want the DerivedClass to contain an array of BaseObjects. I want it to contain an array of DerivedObjects (which extends BaseObject).